# How do I retrieve the date registered as an array of json?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working on a query from sqlalchemy in flask.

How do I retrieve the date registered as an array of json? (PostgreSQL is DB.)

Below is the array value of json in that column.

```
class business(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'biz'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sales = db.Column(JSONB)

sales={'time': ['10:00', '19:00'], …},
```

I wrote the query as below, but the array [0] and array [1] must match exactly, but they will be searched. No others are searched.

Filter value: `filter_val ['sales'] ['time'] [n]`

Json array of table columns: `business.sales ['time'] [n]`

```
if filter_val['sales']['time'][0]: mQuery = mQuery.filter(business.sales['time'][0].astext.ilike('%' + filter_val['sales']['time'][0] + '%'))

if filter_val['sales']['time'][1]: mQuery = mQuery.filter(business.sales['time'][1].astext.ilike('%' + filter_val['sales']['time'][1] + '%'))
```

What I want is,

If the input array value belongs to the tiem [0] in the past time than the filter value,

In tiem [1], we want to be searched for future times ahead of the filter value.
What should I do?

Or I would like to know how to make the result according to size comparison in the current situation.

I can not find the answer, I ask you this question. I am happy to hear a simple example.